# How can I access a parent variable from a child array using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using knockout and have an array "Properties" and each "Property" can have child "properties"

all is fine except that there is a property of the array "TabID" that should be inherited - for example if it is changed on the parent "Property" it should also change on the child "Property"

I've tried to get this to work by using creating a computed, eg.

```
this.TabID = ko.computed(function(){
return $parent.TabID();
});
```

and then realised that $parent was only available within the foreach loop

I've also tried passing the parent through to in the constructor eg

```
var childproperty = function(parent,[other properties]){
this.TabID = ko.computed(function(){
return parent.TabID(); // OR return parent.TabID;
}
```

could somebody point me in the right direction please? As a side note I also need to be able access the parent for a zero based [i] caclulation

that is each parent property should be properties[i].propitem where i = a computed value based on each parent + their child properties

for example: if parent property 1 has 3 child properties, then parent property 1 should be i=0, childproperties (i=1,2,3) and then parent property 2 would have an "i" of 4

I know... I don't ask for much right, I'm not expecting a perfect solution for my issues but if somebody can at least point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by using the following, hopefully this will help anybody else experiencing the same issue

```
var childproperty = function(parent,[other properties]){
this.parent = ko.observable(parent);
this.TabID = ko.computed(function(){
return this.parent().TabID(); // OR return parent.TabID;
}
```

I also noticed that because my parent was calling adding the child from within a function i couldn't just use "this"

my parent property is now

```
var parentproperty = function([properties]){
var p = this;
p.childproperties = ko.observableArray();
p.TabId = ko.observable(1);
p.addChild = function(){
p.childproperties.push(new childproperty(p,[other properties]));
}
```

this works perfectly - if the parent tabid is changed, the value is reflected by the child property. I only really needed the parent index inside the foreach loop which I accessed with $parentContext.$index()

Comment: Could you not have just passed the parent like so: <div foreach="items"><child data-bind="click: Foo($parent)"

Comment: @Nikos - no, because if you do that, `Foo($parent)` will be executed at the time of binding, you need to set `click` to a "delegate".